# How to dynamically change data-order on a DataTable including hidden rows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I'm trying to change the `data-order` of a `DataTable` for a specific column when a button is clicked. I tried two solutions, but neither of them work. The first one was to iterate through each `<td>` and change the `data-order` attribute to the value of the content of a HTML tag with class defined by the clicked button (this is stored in `className`).

Here is the code:

```
let envTable = $('#env_table').DataTable();
$("td.env").each(function () {
    this.setAttribute('data-order', $(this).find(className).text().trim());
});
```

At the end of the function I do this:

```
envTable.rows().invalidate().draw();
```

This doesn't work, because it iterates only through the visible (not paginated) rows, so not everything is included.

The other solution I tried was to change the variables, which are used by jQuery. I'm iterating through each row and selecting a cell (`value[2]` is the second cell in the row). I search for the value I want (as in the first solution).

```
let envTable = $('#env_table').DataTable();
const data = envTable.rows().data();
data.each(function (value, index) {
    const newDataOrder = $(value[2]['display']).filter(className).html().trim();
    value[2]['@data-order'] =  newDataOrder;
});
```

After this code is executed the `data-order` attribute in each `<td>` doesn't change, but it does change in the structure that jQuery uses. After this, the table can be sorted correctly. If it is sorted (e.g. ascending order), it stays with the `data-order` (in the jQuery data, not in HTML) values that were set before the sorting (and even if they are changed later, they don't affect the sorting).

Comment: Do you use Ajax for paging or do you already have all the data at the client-side?

Comment: @Daniel I have everything on the client-side.

Comment: did you take a look at https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem:

> *it iterates only through the visible (not paginated) rows*

One solution is as follows:

You can iterate over every row in the DataTable (regardless of whether it is in the current displayed records or not) - and you can access the corresponding HTML nodes.

From there, you can manipulate the `data-order` attribute as needed.

```
envTable.rows().data().each( function ( rowData, index ) {
  var dataNode = envTable.cells(index, 0).nodes().to$()[0];
  console.log(dataNode); // just for testing
  console.log(dataNode.textContent); // just for testing
  $(dataNode).attr( "data-order", dataNode.textContent );
} );
envTable.rows().invalidate().draw();
```

Here is a small self-contained demo with some test data to show the process:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="env_table" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="Nixon, Tiger">Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="Winters, Garrett">Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="Cox, Ashton">Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="Kelly, Cedric">Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="Satou, Airi">Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="Williamson, Brielle">Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="Chandler, Herrod">Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="Davidson, Rhona">Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="Hurst, Colleen">Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="Frost, Sonya">Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="Gaines, Jena">Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="Flynn, Quinn">Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <br>

 <button onclick="reOrder();">Click me</button> 

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var envTable;

  function reOrder() {
    envTable.rows().data().each( function ( rowData, index ) {
      var dataNode = envTable.cells(index, 0).nodes().to$()[0];
      $(dataNode).attr( "data-order", dataNode.textContent );
    } );
    envTable.rows().invalidate().draw();
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {

    envTable = $('#env_table').DataTable();

} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Each value in the Name column contains a `data-order` attribute. For example:

```
<td data-order="Nixon, Tiger">Tiger Nixon</td>
```

In my test data I use this to sort the names by last name, instead of first name:

[image]

There is a button which runs the `reOrder()` function. This is where the row iteration takes place, and where the DOM nodes are accessed - and then changed.

In my case, I change each `data-order` attribute so that it matches the display name:

```
<td data-order="Tiger Nixon">Tiger Nixon</td>
```

After the re-draw, the data is displayed ordered by first name.